# Csharp The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating UI from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724972/updating-ui-from-a-different-thread)
>   [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423422/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Good day to all.
I have problem with my chat application, i need to refresh my chat all the time but the error is prompting. I dont know how to fix this issue. i hope someone can help me. 
here is my code:

```
void timerChatRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChatRefresh));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ChatRefresh()
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=...; Database=...; Uid=...; Password=...;");
        ds.Clear();
        da.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from chatmessagetbl";
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.Fill(ds, "chatmessagetbl");
        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["chatmessagetbl"].Rows)
        {
            textBlockChatArea.Text += item["username"].ToString() + ": " + item["message"].ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lots of things wrong with this code: new thread on each timer tick; not disposing connection; updating UI controls on a thread

Comment: WPF? WinForms? This is a duplicate. [You need to manipulate on `textBlockChatArea.Text` on the correct thread](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=calling+thread+cannot+access+this+object+because+a+different+thread+owns+it).

Comment: pardon, im still beginner on using Thread class. im using wpf

Answer (score 1):

try textBlockChatArea.Invoke("delegate to a method that update the Text property")

```
1. Declare a delegate   
    public delegate void UpdateChatAreaCallback(string text);
2. Create a method that will update the textbox:
    public void UpdateChatArea(string text){textBlockChatArea.Text += text;}
3. Invoke the method:
    textBlockChatArea.Invoke(new UpdateChatAreaCallback(UpdateChatArea, "new text"));
```